# Swift 3, framework IBOutlet properties always unwrapped optional

Tags: ios, swift, iboutlet, ios-frameworks

I am using a framework to provide custom UI elements in my main project. There are class properties for the UI element classes within the framework. Each of these classes extend common iOS classes, and have their own .xib files.

For instance:

```
open class BaseTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet public var title: UILabel!

  open func setContentDimmed(_ dimmed:Bool) {
    if dimmed {
       self.title.alpha = 0.3 // < crashes with nil object
    } else {
       self.title.alpha = 1.0 // < crashes with nil object
   }
}
```

The problem is that when I instantiate a BaseTableViewCell object and call the setContentDimmed(true) func, it crashes. The only way I can make it work is if I change

```
@IBOutlet public var title: UILabel!
```

to an optional like:

```
@IBOutlet public var title: UILabel?
```

then I MUST unwrap it or its nil (even though its NOT declared as un unwrapped optional in the framework)

```
    open class BaseTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
      @IBOutlet public var title: UILabel?

      open func setContentDimmed(_ dimmed:Bool) {
        if let titleLabel = self.title {
          if dimmed {
           titleLabel.alpha = 0.3 // < doesn't crash, works
          } else {
           titleLabel.alpha = 1.0 // < doesn't crash, works
          }
       }

    }
```

This was working before moving BaseTableViewCell into my framework. Now its always an optional that MUST be unwrapped or it's nil. Any idea whats going on here?

I've tried everything - Im out of ideas.

Comment: Can you show how you are initializing the object, as well as when you are calling your setContentDimmed method? These outlets are set at certain points in the view lifecycle and if you try to use them before, they are nil. My guess is that you are calling the method too early...

Comment: Make sure `setContentDimmed` is only called after (or from) `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this?

```
@IBOutlet public var title: UILabel!{
    didSet{
        guard dimmed != nil { title.alpha = 1.0; return }
        title.alpha = dimmed! ? 0.3 : 1.0
    }
}

var dimmed: Bool? {
    didSet{
        guard title != nil else { return }
        title.alpha = dimmed! ? 0.3 : 1.0
    }
}
```

You are most likely just calling the `setContentDimmed` before the property is even set.